# Gaming on VM Window 10 but got dx11 feature level 10.0 request issue

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, steam

I'm using MacOS tried to use VM window 10 to run PUGB (Downloaded from Steam)but received a msg saying "dx11 feature level 10.0 request to run engine"
I tried roll back driver solution but VM window itself don't have the previous version I guess.

I've done some googling knowing some user got the same msg on their physical pc but worked on VM window 10.

Azure's  Standard NV6 (6 vcpus, 56 GB memory) is my VM' server and thinking will the problem solved if I upgrade the spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NV Series VMs are available with single or multiple NVDIA GPUs as part
>   of the Azure N Series offering. These VMs are optimized for remote
>   visualization and VDI scenarios, using frameworks such as OpenGL and
>   DirectX.

From this description, the NV series VMs have the DirectX function. For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industry/manufacturing/compute-in-manufacturing-overview#remote-desktop-protocol). And to take advantage of the GPU capabilities of Azure N-series VMs running Windows, NVIDIA GPU drivers must be installed. You can take a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/n-series-driver-setup) and it will show you how to install the drivers. Good luck.